# Decreasing One Variable as Another Increases

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

I am putting together a small game in Java, one of the problems I have encountered is increasing the speed of the animation as the player character's movement speed increases.

To increase the speed of animation, the time each frame of the animation is displayed must be decreased, from a maximum of '0.2' for the slowest speed and '0.1' for the highest speed.

My current code works, but it is quite clearly a little clumsy. Unfortunately, I can't think of an elegant solution to replace it.

```
public float getAnimationSpeed()
{
    float _absVel = Math.abs(_vel.x);

    if(_absVel > 10 && _absVel <= 50)
    {
        return 0.1f;
    }
    else if(_absVel > 50 && _absVel <= 150)
    {
        return 0.075f;
    }
    else if(_absVel > 150)
    {
        return 0.05f;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0f;
    }
}
```

You might notice the function may also return a zero, which is used to display the animation as still(For example, when the player character has a velocity of 0, the animation shouldn't be playing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be more dynamic, instead of reasoning with "steps" :

```
public float getAnimationSpeed()
{
    float _absVel = Math.abs(_vel.x);
    float offset = 0; //whatever you want

    if(_absVel<=10){
        return 0f;
    }
    else{
        return ((1/_absVel)+offset)f;
    }
}
```

You can of course change the "1" and the offset to another value that matches the result you want.

I hope it helped !

PS/ You probably also want to check if the result is over your maximum or under your minimum, which I didn't do.

Comment: You could use `MathUtils.clamp()` to clamp the final animation value between your maximum and minimum

Comment: This looks a far better solution, thank you! One question, could you explain briefly how the offset works?

Comment: The offset allows you to adjust the result as you want.
For example here, with an offset of 0, you will have : _absvel=10 --> result=0.1, and _absvel=100 --> result=0.01
But with an offset of 0.1, you will have : _absvel=10 --> result=0.2 and _abslevel=100 --> result=0.11

The more you increase your offset, the less _absVel will have an influence on your final result.